# My Laptop is shut-down because of insufficient memory while Google colaboratory is running

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, darknet

I ran the darknet to execute YOLO object detection machine learning in Google colaboratory.
I am observing the process of machine learning on chrome of my Mac laptop.
However, the memory usage of my laptop(Not Google colaboratory's memory!) became too huge to open the google colaboratory after a while. 
My laptop memory is 16GB and it is not enough to open it.

I don't understand why my laptop memory is used even if the machine learning is executed in cloud server.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the error message, the most common cause of this issue is that third party cookies are disabled in your browser.

See here for a description of why Colab needs third party cookies to be enabled:
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html

Reproducing the relevant snippet below:

> Why prompt to enable third-party cookies?
>
> Colaboratory uses HTML
>   iframes and service workers hosted on separate origins in order to
>   display rich outputs securely. Browsers require enabling third-party
>   cookies to use the service workers within iframes. An alternative to
>   enabling third-party cookies for all sites is to whitelist the
>   following hostname in your browser settings: googleusercontent.com.